# How to build a multi-level menu

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, menu, submenu

I am totally new to android dev so here I am asking.
I would like you to give me some hints about how to build a menu like this:

[image: Side menu]

All items are clickable. I am not sure how to use `ListView` in case like this.
My intention is to build side menu like 4sq or many others. I know how to build some menu from Android docs, so all I need you to help me with is the content.

Answer (score 0):

you can see this exemple

enjoy yourself

[Android expandable list](http://blog.ace-dev.fr/2011/10/07/tutoriel-android-partie-15-expandable-list/)

Comment: well, i dont want expandable, just multi-level, expanded on all times :)